# why insertmany not working using mongoos with transactions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to insert data using `inertMany` .but I am not able to insert the data why ?I am using `mongoose session` if any error occurred then I roll back changes

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-bell-9u0bz

```
app.get("/saveData", async (req, res, next) => {
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();
  try {
    const data = [
      {
        empid: "Ad",
        id: 4,
        date: "19-Jul-2019"
      },
      {
        empid: "Bc",
        id: 56,
        date: "18-Jul-2019"
      },

      {
        empid: "C",
        id: 6,
        date: "11-Jul-2019"
      }
    ];
    console.log("before save");
    let saveBlog = await BlogPostModel.insertMany(data, { session }); //when fail its goes to catch
    await session.commitTransaction();
    return res.send(saveBlog);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    await session.abortTransaction();
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't appear to have understood the [marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435616/how-to-use-mongodb-transaction-using-mongoose) or the [comment on your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58143612/2313887), here's a direct demonstration:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

const blogPostSchema = new Schema({
  id: { type: Number, unique: true },
  empid: String,
  date: Date
});

const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', blogPostSchema);

const sampleData = [
  { empid: "test13", id: 6, date: '11-Jul-2019' },
  { empid: "test123", id: 4, date: '19-Jul-2019' },
  { empid: "test13", id: 4, date: '18-Jul-2019' }
];

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // Clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.values(conn.models).map(m => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // Collections must existi in transactions
    await Promise.all(
      Object.values(conn.models).map(m => m.createCollection())
    );


    // With Transaction
    log("With Transaction");
    let session = await conn.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    try {
      await BlogPost.insertMany(sampleData, { session });
      await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch(e) {
      // Show the error and abort
      log({ err: e.errmsg, result: e.result.result.writeErrors });
      await session.abortTransaction();
    }

    log({ results: (await BlogPost.find()) });

    // No transaction
    log("Without Transaction");
    try {
      await BlogPost.insertMany(sampleData);
    } catch(e) {
      // Show the error
      log({ err: e.errmsg, result: e.result.result.writeErrors });
    }

    log({ results: (await BlogPost.find()) });


  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }


})();
```

And the output:

```
Mongoose: blogposts.createIndex({ id: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
Mongoose: blogposts.deleteMany({}, {})
"With Transaction"
Mongoose: blogposts.insertMany([ { _id: 5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a2, empid: 'test13', id: 6, date: 2019-07-10T14:00:00.000Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a3, empid: 'test123', id: 4, date: 2019-07-18T14:00:00.000Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a4, empid: 'test13', id: 4, date: 2019-07-17T14:00:00.000Z, __v: 0 } ], { session: ClientSession("650da06d23544ef8bc1d345d93331d1e") })
{
  "err": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.blogposts index: id_1 dup key: { id: 4 }",
  "result": [
    {
      "code": 11000,
      "index": 2,
      "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.blogposts index: id_1 dup key: { id: 4 }",
      "op": {
        "_id": "5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a4",
        "empid": "test13",
        "id": 4,
        "date": "2019-07-17T14:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: blogposts.find({}, { projection: {} })
{
  "results": []
}
"Without Transaction"
Mongoose: blogposts.insertMany([ { _id: 5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a5, empid: 'test13', id: 6, date: 2019-07-10T14:00:00.000Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a6, empid: 'test123', id: 4, date: 2019-07-18T14:00:00.000Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a7, empid: 'test13', id: 4, date: 2019-07-17T14:00:00.000Z, __v: 0 } ], {})
{
  "err": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.blogposts index: id_1 dup key: { id: 4 }",
  "result": [
    {
      "code": 11000,
      "index": 2,
      "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.blogposts index: id_1 dup key: { id: 4 }",
      "op": {
        "_id": "5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a7",
        "empid": "test13",
        "id": 4,
        "date": "2019-07-17T14:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: blogposts.find({}, { projection: {} })
{
  "results": [
    {
      "_id": "5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a5",
      "empid": "test13",
      "id": 6,
      "date": "2019-07-10T14:00:00.000Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5d8f28ac462a1e1a8c6838a6",
      "empid": "test123",
      "id": 4,
      "date": "2019-07-18T14:00:00.000Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that when the transaction is in use there are no items inserted into the collection. Using the `insertMany()` with the default behavior of `ordered: true` will insert all *batched* items up until the point any error is encountered.

Note also as stated since you are indeed expecting an **error** you **must** include such a statement in it very own `try..catch` or similar error handler. Otherwise any error ( which is expected in the example case ) would simply fall to the *outer* `catch`, which of course in the demonstration simply exits the program.

---

Not actually in the question itself but something not actually mentioned in the demonstrations of [How to use MongoDB transaction using Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53440397/2313887) is indeed that you should be aware that *whlist a transaction is active* you **must** also include the `session` attribute on **any** subsequent reads in order to see the changes made within that transaction.

For instance, the following would show no content in a collection:

```
let session = await conn.startSession();
session.startTransaction();

try {
  await BlogPost.insertMany(sampleData, { session });
  let documents = await BlogPost.find(); // This would return nothing
  await session.commitTransaction();
} catch(e) {
  // Show the error and abort
  log({ err: e.errmsg, result: e.result.result.writeErrors });
  await session.abortTransaction();
}
```

However including the `session` within a `find()` will actually show what is inserted:

```
try {
  await BlogPost.insertMany(sampleData, { session });
  // Actually includes the session and therefore the state
  let documents = await BlogPost.find({},{ session });

  await session.commitTransaction();
} catch(e) {
  // Show the error and abort
  log({ err: e.errmsg, result: e.result.result.writeErrors });
  await session.abortTransaction();
}
```

And of course that *read* would in this case be dependent on the `insertMany()` *not* failing for any reason, since any error would result in exiting to the `catch` before the next request was made.

Once a transaction is committed, it is of course available to the global state of the connection. But whilst *in progress* only operations which include the same `session` information on which the transaction was started will have visibility of any changes implemented within that transaction.

Comment: thanks for answering .I have one query .till now I did not get what happened when I inserted this `{ empid: "test13", id: 45, date: '18-Jul-2019' }` data instead of this `{ empid: "test13", id: 4, date: '18-Jul-2019' }`

Comment: after this, all three documents should be inserted in collection correct? but it is still giving error .no data inserted

Comment: @user944513 Please take the time to read and even run the example above in order to understand it. I have clearly stated that **ANY** error would result here in a fallback to `abortTransaction()` in which case nothing will be written in the case where there is an active transaction. You can always inspect the error object returned, which does include information for each item in the array given to `insertMany()` which causes a failure. Noting also that the default `ordered: true` will immediately fail on the very first error and make no other attempts.

Comment: Hi friend! Can you please give a hand here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63920298/mongoose-insertmany-with-session

Comment: @NeilLunn what if I pass ordered: false in insertMany?

Answer (score 0):

For who get the error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" while passing session as option in inserMany, this errors come because your mongo is running as standalone servers, to fix this can refer npm package run-rs or following this answer to fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60603587/9611273