# MongoError: This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using `"mongoose": "^5.7.1"` in my Node.js project. I am making an api which involves updating in two documents. So, I am using the transactions like following:

```
// Start the transaction
session = await mongoose.startSession()
session.startTransaction()

await Promise.all([
   <1st update operation>,
   <2nd update operation>
])

// Commit the transaction
session.commitTransaction()
```

When I hit this api on my local environment, I get following error:

> MongoError: This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string.

When I hit this api on remote environment, then it runs fine. I am using https://www.clever-cloud.com as database cloud and AWS as api cloud.

As written in error message, I have tried to put `retryWrites=false`

- at the end of connection string that I am passing to mongoose as `mongodb://${ip}:${port}/${this.MONGO_DATABASE}?retryWrites=false`
- with options as `retryWrites: false` passed to the `mongoose.connect` method.

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${ip}:${port}/${this.MONGO_DATABASE}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    retryWrites: false
  }, (err) => {...})
```

None of the above resolved the issue.

Below is the output of `mongo --version` command:

```
db version v4.0.13
git version: bda366f0b0e432ca143bc41da54d8732bd8d03c0
allocator: system
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

I have debug and find the actual error behind throwing this error is:

> MongoError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos

Please suggest something.

Comment: I started to see these errors as well. I am using Mlab on Heroku. But adding the option on the client solved this. I just tried the URI version and it works as well. Strange.

Comment: I am using a standalone server and that is causing this error. The initial error was not the actual and the later one can be resolved with replica-set or shared clusters. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-rs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transactions are undoubtedly the most exciting new feature in MongoDB 4.0. But unfortunately, most tools for installing and running MongoDB start a standalone server as opposed to a replica set. If you try to start a session on a standalone server, you'll get this error.

This issue can be resolved by using **replica-sets** on your local environment.

I have used [run-rs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-rs) for this purpose.

Answer (score 23):

As suggested in accepted answer, you need to have your local server to be run as a replica set to be able to perform transactions, as opposed to standalone server.

However, in addition to the proposed solution, you can easily convert your Standalone local db to a Replica Set **without using any third-party tool**, by following instructions in [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/), summarized as follows:

1. Stop your standalone mongod instance, and restart it with the `replSet` argument.

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/db0 --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost
```

2. Connect to your instance with a `mongo` shell, and initiate the new Replica Set.

```
rs.initiate()
```

Now you should have a Replica Set instead of a Standalone mongodb server, where you can perform transactions on your local environment to update multiple documents at once!

**Do not forget** to include the `replSet` argument every time you want to start the server, otherwise it will be started as Standalone. I simply use the same command as in step 1 to run it again.

---

Alternatively, you can deploy a new Replica Set from scratch for testing environment following these other instructions in [MongoDB documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/)

Comment: This helped with the much needed solution, thank you very much. Have been struggling with the issue for hours

Answer (score 6):

## Please try adding `&retryWrites=false` to your connection string

--

I actually got the errors mentioned in the OP when connecting to our remote db server, whereas it was working locally.
I contacted our mongo hosted support before trying the suggestion that is in the error.

--

This is what our hosted mongo site (mLab) said :

It's likely your app's driver was updated to a more recent version which is attempting to use a WiredTiger-only feature. As the error mentions, you'll need to add &retryWrites=false to your connection string.

https://docs.mlab.com/faq/#why-am-i-getting-the-transaction-numbers-are-only-allowed-on-storage-engines-that-support-document-level-locking-error

Comment: You should add into string connection ?retryWrites=false and NOT &retryWrites=false

Comment: It depends if there are already URL parameters on your connection string, if so use &, if not use ?

Comment: On Ubuntu, you will need to use | 
sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --replSet rs1 --bind_ip localhost
| since the database is generally installed on /var/lib/mongodb.
Post this, enter a mongo shell and then initiate like so. In the terminal, | 
mongo | 
rs.initiate()

Answer (score 2):

Please Edit `App/Config/database` file Add `'retryWrites'=>false` in Mongodb Connection String

write Mongo db connection

```
'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'lo*****'),
            'port'     => *****,
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'options'  => [
                'database'=> env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
                'retryWrites'=>false
            ]
        ],
```

Save And Run

Comment: I can't find this file

Comment: @TayyabFerozi You have to create this file as Database configuration file, where you define your db constants in environment variables through this file in your nodejs project.