# What type is Mongoose.startSession in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, transactions

I have an Express/Typescript project using mongoose, made a loader like this:

```js
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    import { Db } from 'mongodb';
    import config from '../config';
    
    export default async (): Promise<Db> => {
      const connection = await mongoose.connect(config.databaseURL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      });
    
      return connection.connection.db;
    };
    
    export async function withTransaction (func: any) {
      const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    
      session.startTransaction();
    
      try {
        await func(session);
        await session.commitTransaction();
      } catch (error) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
        throw error;
      } finally {
        session.endSession();
      }
    }
```

I want to make a transaction and here what is I did:

```js
return await withTransaction(async (session: ClientSession) => {
    try {
        const newTransit = await Transit.create(userData, {session});
        //...some other inserts
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Typescript shows this error on session type:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '{ session: ClientSession; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: NativeError, doc: ITransit & Document<any, {}>) => void'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'session' does not exist in type '(err: NativeError, doc: ITransit & Document<any, {}>) => void'.
```

What type should I use for the session?

Comment: Based on your error, I guess you have to pass a callback

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that to use options in create method, we have to pass the first argument as an array. So it would be like this:

```
const newTransit = await Transit.create([userData], {session});
```

Then we should add retryWrites=false in our connection string that needs a MongoDB replica set. Here is more information:

[MongoError: This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58589631/mongoerror-this-mongodb-deployment-does-not-support-retryable-writes-please-ad)